# Return users who follow me and I follow

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hi I'm trying to do this function, my problem is that inside the function in the console.log it does return, but in the return it returns as undefined

```
async function followThisUser(identify_user_id, user_id) {
var following = await Follow.findOne({ "user": identify_user_id, "followed": user_id }).exec((err, follow) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(follow)
    return follow;
});

var followed = await Follow.findOne({ "user": user_id, "followed": identify_user_id }).exec((err, follow) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(follow)
    return follow;
});

return {
    following: following,
    followed: followed
}
```

}

Comment: in your final return put your key value in quotes "" , e.g. "following" : following

Comment: Thanks for responding, this didn't work for me. My problem is that the return doesn't put a value on the variable. Thank you

Comment: ah, then its most likely a scope error. put your final return inside the async function, or declare your variables as a global initially.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the console.log is showing correct value, then you can try something like this:

```
async function followThisUser(identify_user_id, user_id) {
let obj = {}
await Follow.findOne({ "user": identify_user_id, "followed": user_id }).exec((err, follow) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(follow)
    obj['following'] = follow; //setting the required object value
});

await Follow.findOne({ "user": user_id, "followed": identify_user_id }).exec((err, follow) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(follow)
    obj['followed'] = follow; //set the required value
});

console.log(obj); // see if the obj has actual value
return obj;
}
```

As a friendly suggestion try to keep variable names so that they are differentiable from each other. This really helps in the long run!

Hope that helps! Happy coding!